# Question about weak* convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a vector space and $V^{*}$ the associated dual space of $V$.

Definition of weak$^{*}$ Convergence:
A sequence ${F_n} \subset V$ is called weak$^{*}$ convergent to $F \in V^{*}$, if

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_n(v)=F(v)$ for all $v \in V$

My Question:

Weak$^{*}$ Convergence just looks like pointwise convergence. Are they the same?

I assume not because why would there be an extra name if they are the same.

Comment: Yes, this is pointwise convergence, where the "points" are elements of $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is point-wise convergence. The reason why it is called weak-* convergence is that is is weaker than the usual weak convergence in the dual $V^*$. For weak convergence, you have to test your elements on all of the bidual space $V^{**}$ but for weak-* you only "test" them on $V$, which is strictly contained in $V^{**}$ via the canonical identification, unless the space is reflexive.